# Python git to create PR to master

Tags: python, github-api

I have created a script that will locally push the branch to remote using python git lib.
But at the same time, I would like to create the PR for the master branch...I tried to look into all the options, but I can't find any way to push other than API calls

```
git_pulls_api = "https://github.com/api/v3/repos/{0}/{1}/pulls".format(
        project_name,
        repo_name)
```

Is there any python git libs which will do this?

Comment: You will need a *Github* Python client. Pull requests are not git specific concept. But that will still just create the necessary API calls internally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+python